# How Many Documents are Required for Latent Semantic Indexing?

Tags: latent-semantic-analysis, latent-semantic-indexing

How many documents are generally required to produce good results for latent semantic indexing?  By good results I mean relevant results are given for queries

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on the specific application and the size of the vocabulary. It is reasonable to expect LSI to be good with 100,000 documents. But it can improve when you have millions of documents.

Comment: But is there a minimum threshold below which it absolutely wouldn't work.  In terms of vocabulary, my application is a standard english vocabulary

Comment: There are no absolutes here. You will just get a gradual degradation in quality as your matrix becomes smaller. Only thing you can do is try it and see if it works and keep in mind that a typical application would have thousands of documents.